# Designing a hypothesis test for a gamma distributed RV and a given significance level

Tags: statistics

I am stuck at the follwoing problem:

Consider the exponentially distributed RVs $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_9$ with parameter $\lambda$. We reject $H_0: \lambda \ge 1$ in favor of $H_A: \lambda < 1$ if $\overline{X} \ge k$.

We want to reach the significance level $\alpha = 0.05$. Find $k$ and calculate the  powerfunction at $\lambda = 0.5$.

Since the sum of $n$ exponentially distributed RVs (with parameter $\lambda$) is $\Gamma_{n, \ 1/\lambda}$ distributed the problem reduces itself to find a $k$ such that

$$\alpha = P_\lambda(\overline{X} \ge k) = \int_{k}^\infty \frac{1}{9}\cdot\Gamma_{9, \ 1/\lambda } \ \ d\lambda$$

if I am not mistaken. But I am haveing a hard time finding a suitable $k$. Could you help me ?

Comment: It depends on your tools.  R's `qgamma` and `pgamma` functions will give you $k$ and then the power.  Or you could use a normal approximation

Comment: I am supposed to do this by hand unfortunately

Comment: By parameter $\lambda$, do you mean the pdf is $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\mathbf1_{x>0}$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom $\lambda$ is likely to be the rate or mean of the exponential distribution.  Given that the critical region is associated with low $\lambda$ and higher values, I think we can assume $\lambda$ is the rate

Comment: Thats right the pdf is defined via $\lambda$

Comment: In that case you can get $k$ as a fractile of $\chi^2_{18}$ distribution using a chi-square table, because with the above pdf,

$X_i\stackrel{\text{ i.i.d }}\sim\text{Exp}\text{ with mean }1/\lambda\implies 2\lambda X_i\stackrel{\text{ i.i.d }}\sim\text{Exp}\text{ with mean }2\equiv\chi^2_2\implies 2\lambda\sum_{i=1}^9 X_i\sim\chi^2_{18}$.

In other words, $18\lambda\overline X\sim\chi^2_{18}$.

Comment: Interesting/important problem with helpful comments by @Henry and StubbornAtom and lots of engagement on your part (+1). I thought it might be generally useful to put the pieces together, address power, show some usage of R, and some illustrations. Thus my Answ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hypothesis test for exponential rate.** Suppose $n = 60,$ so that you have a random sample $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{50}$
from $\mathsf{Exp}(\text{rate} = \lambda).$ Then $\bar X
\sim \mathsf{Gamma}(\text{shape} = n, \text{rate} = n\lambda).$

If you are testing $H_0: \lambda \ge 1$ against $H_a:\lambda < 1,$
then you want to reject when $\bar X \ge c$ where $c$ cuts probability
$0.05$ from the *upper tail* of the null distribution 
$\mathsf{Gamma}(50,50).$ [Notice that large values of $\bar X$ correspond to small values of $\lambda$ because the exponential mean $\mu = 1/\lambda.]$

In R one finds $c = 1.243421.$

```
qgamma(.95, 50, 50) 
[1] 0.7792947
```

[If you are allergic to software, then you could use the relationship between gamma and chi-squared distributions to get $c$ from printed tables of the chi-squared distribution.]

***Example not leading to rejection.*** For example, suppose I have a sample `x` with $\bar X = 1.008.$

```
set.seed(2005)    # generate fake data with rate 1
x = rexp(50, 1)
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.01236 0.27856 0.69518 1.00772 1.42997 6.01451
```

Then you do not reject $H_0: \lambda \le 1$ because $1.008 < c.$
The p-value of this test is the probability $0.46$ under the null distribution
that a mean greater than $1.008$ is observed.

```
 1 - pgamma(1.008, 50, 50)
 [1] 0.4587632
```

[image]

**Power of the test.** Suppose that in fact $\lambda = 1/2.$ Then the power of this test
is the probability $0.9989$ of rejecting (getting $X \ge 1.2434)$ under the alternative
distribution $\mathsf{Gamma}(n, n/2).$

Intuitively, with $n = 50$ observations, it is not difficult to tell the difference between
an exponential rate of $\lambda = 1$ and an exponential rate of $\lambda = 1/2.$ (In the figure below, the two density curves have little area in common.)

```
1 - pgamma(1.2434, 50, 50/2)
[1] 0.9989138
```

***Example leading to rejection*** As an example, suppose we have a sample `y` with $\bar Y = 1.573.$
Then we reject $H_0: \lambda \ge 1$ in favor of the alternative
$H_0: \lambda < 1.$ because $\bar Y = 1.573 > 1.2434.$

```
set.seed)2018)    # generate fake data with rate 1/2
y = rexp(50, 1/2)
summary(y)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.01971 0.47256 1.01072 1.57307 2.22232 8.82067
```

The p-value for the Y-sample is very small (much below 5%).

```
1 - pgamma(1.573, 50, 50)
[1] 0.0002244243
```

[It is difficult to use printed distribution tables to
find p-values.]

In the figure below, the p-value is the very small area under the grey null curve to the right of the vertical dotted line (at the observed value $\bar Y).$ The power of the test is the large
area under the heavy black alternative curve
to the right of the vertical red line (at the
critical value).

[image]